# Order Tracking not showing up in shipment email

Tags: shipping, email, magento-1.6

Our site is sending shipment emails, but the email contains no tracking info.  I've created a new template based off of the default one and added **{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}** but that part of the email is empty.  When I click "Track Shipment" in the admin panel, it brings up the tracking number and a link to UPS,

We have a UPS API integrated to create shipments directly from Magento.  It appears that the shipment email is being sent before the tracking number comes back.  There is also a green status message that says "The shipment has been created." before any of the information like weight and dimensions are entered.

Looks like I get to dig through some code and move some things around.

What could I be missing?
Any help would be great here.

Comment: Having same issue with Magento CE 1.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly a little late for this, but....

There's a thread on the Magento forums here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9594/

If you look at the code for  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api`, the confirmation email is being sent out as part of the `create()` function. Then, the tracking details are added later with a call to `addTrack()`, but by that time, the email is already sent.

The suggested solution is to edit the source and move the call to `$shipment->sendEmail()`, but I suspect that that isn't the most elegant solution - I suspect you'd be better off extending the class instead, and doing it that way.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I ended up doing.  I never came back here to update, but thanks for the answer

Comment: we can make one copy of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api in local pool, and customize it.

Comment: This is gold, exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That solution works for me, but be careful as another file extends the `create()` function. So you need to also comment the call to `$shipment->sendEmail()` in Sales/Order/Shipment/Api/V2.php

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without editing/extending Magento core is to modify your API call to not send the shipping email in the first place when creating the order. Just send it after adding the tracking code:

1. Call `sales_order_shipment.create` with `$email = FALSE` see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api_V2`

   ```
   public function create($orderIncrementId, $itemsQty = array(), $comment = null, $email = false, $includeComment = false)
   ```
2. Add the tracking code by calling `sales_order_shipment.addTrack`

   ```
   public function addTrack($shipmentIncrementId, $carrier, $title, $trackNumber)
   ```
3. Call the method `sales_order_shipment.sendInfo` to trigger the shipment email

   ```
   public function sendInfo($shipmentIncrementId, $comment = '')
   ```

Thats are actually better than modifying Magento default behavior. Good luck